# Windows Tracert tcp

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

I'm trying to implement tracert using tcp on Windows. I'm using Winsock. Socket I use is SOCK_STREAM.

The problem is how do I get the address of the host with the next TTL. As far as I get I cannot use recvfrom function in this case because TCP is a connection based protocol so recv is equal is recvfrom in this context.
I tried to use getpeername but I still get only target node's IP address.

Moreover. Setting even TTL = 0 to the IP packet still results finds its way to the target machine and I get the response.

Comment: Can you post part of the code that doesn't work the way you expected? Maybe it is also easier to port tcptraceroute to windows than write it from scratch.

Comment: Well the main problem is from what I've seen that you have still to create a receiving ICMP socket to get the "TTL exceeded" message, no matter what sending transport protocol is. But you can only create raw ICMP sockets. And you have to have admin rights for it. Another opportunity is to use winpcap lib for that but it also requires admin rights to install the driver. And I would prefer the way that does not require admin rights

Comment: I would recommend then to rewrite this question or ask a new question for this specific problem. But as far as I know (or read) winsock needs administrative rights on raw sockets ("On Windows NT, raw socket support requires administrative privileges", found on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx a little bit after the middle of the page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracert` (or `traceroute`) doesn't work with TCP but with ICMP (like `ping`). The TTL should be started by **1** and then incremented by 1 until the destination was reached.

More can be found on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute#Implementation

Comment: It's true but it's not what I'm asking. I've already implemented tracert using ICMP request. Now I want implement it using TCP request and catching ICMP responds telling that TTL = 0 with the same technique as TTL incrementing. You can do it in Linux with command tcptraceroute: http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptraceroute

Comment: Actually `traceroute` (Linux) does work with TCP. See the `-T` option. It uses a TCP SYN to get past routers that might block ICMP. You can target a specific port with `-p`.